# Get portfolio returns and attributions from Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg

I have a mostly general question.
I have a Bloomberg Terminal, I have different portfolios I created in it. So, I know their names.
I want to get from Bloomberg PORT information like:

1. Total return for different periods.
2. Attributions for different periods.

I'm trying to use 'Rblpapi' package for this, but I can't understand how to get the information I need through this package.
So, is it possible to get this information through 'Rblpapi' or not? If not, what package should I use for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it you can do that - you probably need to export the data from PORT directly.

Comment: @assylias Unfortunatelly, data export from PORT cannot be automatized... Is there no way to get data from PORT directly through the API?(((

Comment: Your best bet is to talk to Blomberg support - I believe there is a way to automate that but it requires an Enterprise licence, which you may have.